# How to show <hr> when printing, but not when viewing on screen

Tags: printing

I'm trying to print a line on paper which I don't want to see on screen. This is what I do:

```
<style media="screen" type="text/css">
.print {
    display: none;
}
</style>
<span class="print"><hr></span>
```

The ruler is displayed on screen as well as on paper. If I put anything else inside the span it isn't displayed. Any idea?

Comment: Just to be clearer, am I right in thinking, you want the line to display ONLY when printed, but not when viewed on the display screen?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the span, and applying the condition to the `<hr>` tag itself, as this may be overriding. (You could right click on the line, and Inspect Element, which will show you if the style is being overridden).

```
<style>
@media print {
    hr { display:block; }
}

@media screen {
    hr { display:none; }
}
</style>
```

So now you can just use `<hr>` in your markup, and it will only be displayed when printing.

Copy the example below into a HTML file and view it, then go onto Print Preview, and you'll see the lines appearing in the print preview, but not on the screen.

```
<html>
    <style>
        @media print {
            hr { display:block; }
        }

        @media screen {
            hr { display:none; }
        }
    </style>

    <body>
        <h1>This is a title</h1>
        <p>This is some text</p>
        <hr>
        <h1>This is a title</h1>
        <p>This is some text</p>
        <hr>
        <h1>This is a title</h1>
        <p>This is some text</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @FrankSpade ! Don't forget to mark this as your answer if you're satisfied it has helped you :)